# Display Data to spesific column Grid control devexpress using oracle data reader

Tags: c#, oracle11g, devexpress, gridcontrol

I have tried display data from spesific column `ListView` in C# and it was successfull. But I couldn't display it into spesific column in `GridControl` DevExpress.

This my code in `ListView`:

```
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
OracleDataReader dr;
cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT * FROM PERMOHONANDETAIL WHERE PERMOHONANFK = '" + buka.txtID.Text + "'";
cmd.Connection = koneksi_manual.con;
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (dr.Read())
{
    ListViewItem list = new ListViewItem(dr["PEKERJAAN"].ToString());
    list.SubItems.Add(dr["KODEPEKERJAAN"].ToString());
    list.SubItems.Add(dr["PEKERJAAN"].ToString());
    list.SubItems.Add(dr["JOBFORM"].ToString());
    list.SubItems.Add(dr["QTYORDER"].ToString());
    list.SubItems.Add(dr["TARGETPERHARI"].ToString());
    list.SubItems.Add(Convert.ToDateTime(dr["TANGGALSTART"]).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
    list.SubItems.Add(Convert.ToDateTime(dr["TANGGALEND"]).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
    list.SubItems.Add(dr["DURASIHARI"].ToString());
    list.SubItems.Add(dr["NOTES"].ToString());
    buka.listView1.Items.Add(list);
}
dr.Close();
buka.Focus();
buka.ShowDialog();
```

How can I do it into spesific column `GridControl` in DevExpress?
How can I solve this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a class for your rows and use the `List<YourClass>` as `DataSource` for your `GridControl`.
For example, you can create this class:

```
public class GridControlItem
{
    public string KODEPEKERJAAN { get; set; }
    public string PEKERJAAN { get; set; }
    public string JOBFORM { get; set; }
    public string QTYORDER { get; set; }
    public string TARGETPERHARI { get; set; }
    public string TANGGALSTART { get; set; }
    public string TANGGALEND { get; set; }
    public string DURASIHARI { get; set; }
    public string NOTES { get; set; }
}
```

And use it in your `GridControl` as follows:

```
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
OracleDataReader dr;
cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT * FROM PERMOHONANDETAIL WHERE PERMOHONANFK = '" + buka.txtID.Text + "'";
cmd.Connection = koneksi_manual.con;
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

var list = new List<GridControlItem>();

while (dr.Read())
{
    var item = new GridControlItem();

    item.KODEPEKERJAAN = dr["KODEPEKERJAAN"].ToString();
    item.PEKERJAAN = dr["PEKERJAAN"].ToString();
    item.JOBFORM = dr["JOBFORM"].ToString();
    item.QTYORDER = dr["QTYORDER"].ToString();
    item.TARGETPERHARI = dr["TARGETPERHARI"].ToString();
    item.TANGGALSTART = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["TANGGALSTART"]).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
    item.TANGGALEND = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["TANGGALEND"]).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
    item.DURASIHARI = dr["DURASIHARI"].ToString();
    item.NOTES = dr["NOTES"].ToString();

    list.Add(item)
}
dr.Close();

gridControl1.DataSource = list;
```